# Handling reminders timeout

Tags: javascript, timer, bots

I am creating an assistant bot in javascript and I want to support reminders, my problem is that it need to support both short timeouts (10 mins) and long timeouts (a month).
To my understanding using the `setTimeout()` functions wouldn't work for the long timeout, so I thought of using a lookup table and check it every second, but that would be heavy on resources.

I wanted to know if the lookup table it the best option (as far as performance is concerned) and if so whether there are best practices to follow.

Comment: You can look into using [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron), for long term timeouts in case you're using node.js

Comment: you might need a scheduled execution system i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a function `prepareNextReminders(time_in_minutes, callback)` that retrieves reminders in the next X minutes, e.g. one hour. For each of them, creates a setTimeout with the callback and the proper delay and adds the id to a list of prepared reminders.

This function runs every 15 minutes and in each run does the same for the new reminders not already existing in the list of prepared reminders.

Comment: thank you very much, that was what I was looking for